# How can I make hyperlinks 'portable' from machine to machine instead of hard-coded?

Tags: html

I have a simple HTML page and it contains links to pictures and other HTML pages.
I put the webpage on a memory USB. When I insert the memory USB to another PC, I need to change their path in the file. 
How could I do that automatically?

Thank you!

Comment: You are new to the site so some guidelines: - always post your code for these kinda questions.

Comment: Otherwise as you will see down and close votes come flying in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the html to use relative paths rather than absolute paths

i.e.

```
<img src="~/images/image1.png" alt="" />
<a href="home.html" target="_self">Home Page</a>
```

rather than

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/image1.png" alt="" />
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/images/image1.png" alt="" />
```

[Note - the squiggly '`~`' means home directory.
If the web site lives in /this/place and images and in /this/place/images then you use '`images/filename.jpg`' - no leading '`/`']   Michael Durrant.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [relative paths](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm), no adjustments will be necessary.

Comment: +1 yes, relative vs. absolute is probably the issue here.  Thanks for treating the newbie well :)